# Using URL parameters with MongoDB's geospacing and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, geospatial

Probably a really basic question for someone out there. I'm sending a URL through (and example is `localhost:3000/services?lat=50&long=30`). I want to grab the lat and long of the url and place in within a Geospacing query. The current code doesn't produce anything on screen, but it does log the correct values for lat and long:

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    var lat = req.query.lat;
    var long = req.query.long;
    console.log(lat + long);

    db.collection('services', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find( { loc: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ lat, long ] ,
                                                     100 / 3963.2 ] } } } ).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });

    });
};
```

Comment: All parameters are actually "strings" so you would need to `parseFloat` on them where you expect a numeric value ( typically coordinates are floats ).  But also you have the wrong order as geospatial data in MongoDB needs to be in `["longitude","latitude"]` order. This is actually well documented on every operator. ie. [`$centerSphere`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/) in the **important** box, just a little down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Sussed it.

Needed to use `parseInt` on the lat and long variables. Thanks.